# What is the difference between [merge] and [merge,edit] in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, continuous-integration, alm

I have source code in the main. From this main i created a branche development. After changing the development branche i want to merge these changes back to the main. When i do this these changes are marked with [Merge,Edit] while i expect [Merge]. Can anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 3):

(merge) means merge with no real change
(merge,edit) means merge with a change on the file in target with contents from source.
Nice readings on: [What does it mean when Source Control Explorer shows both branch and merge for a changeset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291249/what-does-it-mean-when-source-control-explorer-shows-both-branch-and-merge-for-a)
Unfortunately no msdn pages...

Answer (score 1):

The merge status means that the revision contains a merge from  another branch.

If a particular file is diffrent in the two branches, the file will have the status "merge, edit" because it is both merged from the branch and changed content.

After you perform your merge and check in it, a Conflicts Window appears.You must solve the confics of the file which has "merge,edit" status before check in.